# Proof of group theory

Tags: group-theory

“Prove that the additive group of real numbers doesn’t have any proper subgroup with finite index.”
I want to know how to prove this.

Comment: What's "limited index" mean?

Comment: Finite index, I meant. I’m not sure it’s correct in English. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $G\leq\mathbb{R}$ is a subgroup with $[\mathbb{R}:G]=n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $n\cdot x\in G$ (why?). In particular, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $x = n\cdot(\frac{x}{n})\in G$ so $\mathbb{R}=G$.

Comment: Thank you! You mean this? f:R→G(x→nx) for any x in R, there exists x/n in R s.t. x=f(x/n)=n(x/n) in G. Hence R=G.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!